# Configuration is inaccurate with more Mujoco mj_steps

Tags: simulation, reinforcement-learning, mujoco

I tried to construct a simulation env following [`fetch_pick_and_place`](https://github.com/Farama-Foundation/Gymnasium-Robotics/blob/3a579d6efa2056cce394ffeb5d1ef83a58fea23a/gymnasium_robotics/envs/fetch/fetch_env.py#L416). I noticed that the following code is used to initialize the env:

```
    for _ in range(10):
        self._mujoco.mj_step(self.model, self.data, nstep=self.n_substeps)
```

Similarly, I followed the above code to initialize my own env but got inaccurate configurations. As I reduced the number of loops, I got configurations closer to the desired configuration.

So, my confusion is why more `mj_step`s lead to inaccurate simulation results.